# How Can I call Spring Repository Methods From Services Effectively?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop

I have a code block like below:

```
@Repository
public class SummaryDao implements ISummaryDao {

    public List<Response> reportOfCategory(RequestObject obj){
       ...
    }

    public List<Response> reportOfGroup(RequestObject obj){
       ...
    }

    public List<Response> reportOfSubGroup(RequestObject obj){
       ...
    }

}
```

My Second repository:

```
@Repository
public class ReportDao implements IReportDao {

    public List<Response> reportOfCategory(RequestObject obj){
       ...
    }

    public List<Response> reportOfGroup(RequestObject obj){
       ...
    }

    public List<Response> reportOfSubGroup(RequestObject obj){
       ...
    }

}
```

Then I call them from service class like below:

```
@Service
public class ReportService {

@Autowired
ISummaryDao summaryDao;

@Autowired
IReportDao reportDao;

public List<Response> call(EnumType type, RequestObject obj){

   if(type == Category) {
     return obj.isSummary ? summaryDao.reportOfCategory : reportDao.reportOfCategory;
   }
   if(type == Group) {
     return obj.isSummary ? summaryDao.reportOfGroup : reportDao.reportOfGroup;
   }
   if(type == SubGroup) {
     return obj.isSummary ? summaryDao.reportOfSubGroup : reportDao.reportOfSubGroup;
   }
...
}
```

How can I call them effectively? Actually I want to escape from if-else block and Enum comparison.

Note: Enum comparison can be switch-case.

Note: In this code, I used Spring-Boot EntityManager. I know JPARepository. This question is not related with it.

Comment: Why are you using raw types like `List` ?

Comment: @michalk, I've just editted it. It is just typo.

Comment: I think it is difficult to make recommendations without knowing more about the data and business logic behind your application.Any chance you could provide more details on your database (or data store) structure? If you are able to alter the underlying data structure, that may be the best solution. However, this is hard to know given the provided information. Personally, I found that extending CrudRepository works quite well for the vast majority of use cases., but I guess you do not want/cannot use that for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like below:

I created a IGeneralDao to use common interface.

```
@Repository
public class SummaryDao implements IGeneralDao {

    public List<Response> reportOfCategory(RequestObject obj){
       ...
    }

    public List<Response> reportOfGroup(RequestObject obj){
       ...
    }

    public List<Response> reportOfSubGroup(RequestObject obj){
       ...
    }

}
```

Second Repository:

```
@Repository
public class ReportDao implements IGeneralDao {

    public List<Response> reportOfCategory(RequestObject obj){
       ...
    }

    public List<Response> reportOfGroup(RequestObject obj){
       ...
    }

    public List<Response> reportOfSubGroup(RequestObject obj){
       ...
    }

}
```

To call it:

```
@Service
public class ReportService {

@Autowired
IGeneralDao reportDao, summaryDao;

public List<Response> call(EnumType type, RequestObject obj){
   IGeneralDao generalDao = isSummary ? summaryDao : reportDao;
   switch(type):
      case Category:
          return generalDao.reportOfCategory;
      case Group:
          return generalDao.reportOfGroup;
      case SubGroup:
          return generalDao.reportOfSubGroup;
...
}
```

**To escape from enum comparison:**

```
public interface IGeneralDao {
    <T> T callReports(RequestDto requestDto);
    IGeneralDao setRequestType(EnumType type);
}
```

First Repository:

```
@Repository
public enum ReportDao implements IGeneralDao {
    Category {
        @Override
        public List<Response> callReports(RequestDto requestDto) {
            return ...;
        }
    },
    Group {
        @Override
        public List<Response> callReports(RequestDto requestDto) {
            return ...;
        }
    },
    SubGroup {
        @Override
        public List<Response> callReports(RequestDto requestDto) {
            return ...;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public IGenericDao setEnumType(EnumType type) {
        return valueOf(type.name());
    }
}
```

Second Repository:

```
@Repository
public enum SummaryDao implements IGeneralDao {
    Category {
        @Override
        public Summary callReports(RequestDto requestDto) {
            return ...;
        }
    },
    Group {
        @Override
        public Summary callReports(RequestDto requestDto) {
            return ...;
        }
    },
    SubGroup {
        @Override
        public Summary callReports(RequestDto requestDto) {
            return ...;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public IGenericDao setEnumType(EnumType type) {
        return valueOf(type.name());
    }
}
```

Then call it from main service:

```
@Service
public class ReportService {

@Autowired
IGeneralDao reportDao, summaryDao;

public List<Response> call(EnumType type, RequestObject obj){
   IGeneralDao generalDao = isSummary ? summaryDao : reportDao;
   return generalDao.setEnumType(type).callReports(obj);
}
```